# How do I give a mutable reference to a builder but only an immutable reference to the built object?

Tags: rust, lifetime

When constructing a `FooBuilder`, I want to provide a `&mut Bar`. When I build `Foo` I want to provide a `&Bar` and `Foo` should be able to invoke `&self` methods from `Bar`. In other words, the mutable borrow should only during exist during the life of `FooBuilder`.

```
struct FooBuilder<'a> {
    bar: &'a mut Bar,
}
impl<'a> FooBuilder<'a> {
    fn new(bar: &'a mut Bar) -> Self {
        FooBuilder { bar: bar }
    }
    fn build(&'a self) -> Foo<'a> {
        Foo { bar: &self.bar }
    }
}

struct Foo<'a> {
    bar: &'a Bar,
}

struct Bar;
impl Bar {
    fn bar(&self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut bar = Bar;
    let foo = FooBuilder::new(&mut bar).build();
    bar.bar();
}
```

This code has the error:

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> <anon>:24:15
   |
24 |     let foo = FooBuilder::new(&mut bar).build();
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ does not live long     enough
   |
note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following     statement 1 at 24:48...
  --> <anon>:24:49
   |
24 |     let foo = FooBuilder::new(&mut bar).build();
   |                                                 ^
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the statement at 24:4
  --> <anon>:24:5
   |
24 |     let foo = FooBuilder::new(&mut bar).build();
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
  --> <anon>:24:5
   |
24 |     let foo = FooBuilder::new(&mut bar).build();
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `bar` as immutable because it is also     borrowed as mutable
  --> <anon>:25:5
   |
24 |     let foo = FooBuilder::new(&mut bar).build();
   |                                    --- mutable borrow occurs     here
25 |     bar.bar();
   |     ^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
26 | }
   | - mutable borrow ends here

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: It's not the best etiquette to modify your question in such a way that it invalidates existing answers.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, sorry. You cannot downgrade a mutable reference to a shared one to regain the shared lifetime.

Comment: @Veedrac: Really? The reverse is obvious (once aliased, you cannot guarantee exclusivity) but moving from exclusive to aliased is possible as far as I know.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I am sorry you deleted your answer, you were very close (I would argue the remaining error was a typo).

Comment: @MatthieuM. no worries; I couldn't answer the core meat of the question, so it wasn't a big loss. I read the problem the same as Veedrac; that the mutability should be given up after the builder builds.

Comment: @Shepmaster: If that is the case then Chris' answer will have the gist of it: I don't see how to downgrade a borrow at the moment in Rust (the compiler *could* analyze this deep, but it would be more brittle). It's not necessary here, but I guess that's what happens with reduced examples.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to fix `build`.

In order to transform a `&mut T` into a `&T` you need to *consume* `&mut T` (otherwise you would have aliasing and mutability). This means:

- consuming the builder, not taking a reference to it
- passing the mutable reference, not taking a reference to it

In short, you go from:

```
fn build(&'a self) -> Foo<'a> {
    Foo { bar: &self.bar }
}
```

to:

```
fn build(self) -> Foo<'a> {
    Foo { bar: self.bar }
}
```

This leaves you with a single error:

```
error: cannot borrow `bar` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable [--explain E0502]
  --> <anon>:25:5
24 |>     let foo = FooBuilder::new(&mut bar).build();
   |>                                    --- mutable borrow occurs here
25 |>     bar.bar();
   |>     ^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
26 |>     //foo.bar.bar();
27 |> }
   |> - mutable borrow ends here
```

As far as the compiler can see from the method signatures, `bar` is borrowed mutably and therefore cannot be used directly. The borrow extends until `foo` is dropped.

The fix is very simple: instead of using `bar` directly, use `bar` from its reference in `foo`. Or to make it clear that scope matters:

```
fn main() {
    let mut bar = Bar;
    {
        let foo = FooBuilder::new(&mut bar).build();
        // `bar` currently borrow (mutably) by `foo`, cannot use it directly
        foo.bar.bar();
    }
    // `bar` no longer borrowed, use at your heart's content
    bar.bar();
}
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question; my understanding is that your last step - discarding `foo` before using `bar` - is against the OP's wishes. OP wants `foo` and `bar` to both be usable immutably together.

Comment: @Veedrac: That's not what I had gotten out of the question at all, but I now see how it could be read this way too. Let's see what the OP will think of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar if you don't mind wrapping `bar` in an `Rc`.  The trick is that if there's only one `Rc` reference, you can get an `&mut` reference to the contents.  This is sort of backwards; instead of downgrading `&mut` to `&` at compile time, it's making use of runtime information (reference counts) to "upgrade" from an immutable reference to mutable.

```
use std::rc::Rc;

struct FooBuilder<'a> {
    bar: &'a mut Rc<Bar>,
}
impl<'a> FooBuilder<'a> {
    fn new(bar: &'a mut Rc<Bar>) -> Self {
        FooBuilder { bar: bar }
    }
    fn f(mut self) -> Self {
        Rc::get_mut(self.bar).unwrap().mut_method();
        self
    }
    fn build(&'a self) -> Foo {
        Foo { bar: self.bar.clone() }
    }
}

struct Foo {
    bar: Rc<Bar>,
}

struct Bar;
impl Bar {
    fn bar(&self) {}
    fn mut_method(&mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut bar = Rc::new(Bar);
    let foo = FooBuilder::new(&mut bar).f().build();
    bar.bar();
}
```

[Play link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5c1ebf4f35ff694a0070426866512a2f&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Once the Foo has been constructed with an `Rc` clone, there is more than one reference and a later attempt to get a `mut` reference would panic (or at least return `None` from `Rc::get_mut()`).

This means that you can only do this once; if you want a second `FooBuilder` to create a second `Foo` from the same `bar` it won't work, as you're not allowed any other references if you have an `&mut T`.

This is a little clumsy, though, and there are likely to be better ways of solving the actual problem, depending on the circumstances.

Comment: If you're checking dynamically, a `RefCell` is a lot less heavyweight. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=88a746b54a6cd6e6ede1818c8ce136d2&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: That is true, but doesn't give the "convert to immutable" part. I'm not saying that's necessarily desired though!